# Not sure when to use "exist" and "exists"

Tags: grammaticality

As a non-native English speaker I have never been quite sure how to use the words "exist" and "exists".

For example is the usage of the said words grammatically correct in the following sentences?

> 1: "there would need to exist a point such that..."
> 2: "since the point exists, we conclude that..."

In addition it would be helpful if you could point me to some ELI5-like resource, that explains the surrounding grammatical rules thoroughly.

Comment: to exist, to study, to speak can never be to exists, to studies or to speaks. After 'to' we use the first form of the verb only. The second one is regarding verbs agreeing with the subject. In present indefinite tense, singular subjects (except I, we and you), have verbs with 's' and plural subjects  without 's'. Here, "Point exists..., Points exist;  child cries, children cry, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb 'to exist' works in the same way as any other standard English verb.

1. The infinitive follows *need* as in 'I need to sit down'.
2. 'The point exists' is present tense, third person singular.

Comment: It really is this simple but the question may arise from confusion with the verb "to be" which can have a similar meaning but has its own special grammatical rules. But as this answer says, "to exist" is used and conjugated like a regular English verb, not like "to be"